# Adjust position in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, text

can you help me move this text box to the other side? I can't find what slds or css is needed to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
<lightning-card title="Wallet" icon-name="custom:custom15">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="New" icon-position="right"
                    onclick={openForm} disabled={disableButton}>
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Search Pal" icon-position="left"
                    onclick={showPal}>
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-p-around_x-small slds-size_1-of-6">
                <lightning-input placeholder="Add Deposit" type="number" onchange={getDeposit}>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={walletRecords} columns={walletColumns} onrowaction={addDeposit}>
        </lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: could you share the component's template you are using?

Comment: @McCubo I just updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 12 Grid System, so for the 3rd `div` the css class should be `slds-size_10-of-12`. Also use `slds-float_right` for the `lightning-input` for right alignment.

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-clearfix">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_x-small" variant="brand" label="New" icon-position="right" onclick={openForm}
            disabled={disableButton}>
        </lightning-button>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_x-small" variant="brand" label="Search Pal" icon-position="left" onclick={showPal}>
        </lightning-button>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_10-of-12">
        <lightning-input variant="label-hidden" class="slds-m-right_x-small slds-float_right" placeholder="Add Deposit" type="number" onchange={getDeposit}></lightning-input>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Nice it works. Thanks a lot